# PNG replaced by GIF when browsing with IE

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, png, gif

I have an asp.net C# 3.5 web app, hosting in IIS7 (win 7).

We use `png` image files. Browsing with Chrome, all is fine. With IE, all `<img>` are looking for `gif` version of files !

Comment: what version of ie are you using ?

Comment: This reeks of an HTTP handler somewhere that's deciding what to serve based on the browser making the request. IE surely won't change the extension of a URL based on its MIME type.

Comment: IE10. I noticed that after having updated the "ie.browser" file. I agree that IE will not change html source, by what about IIS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a reference to `ImageControlAdapter`, used for IE6 only, that was also taken into account for IE10.